# Nested quotes when inputting into MySql

Tags: mysql, insert, quotes

I am having problem inserting data into `MySql` table.  For simplicity, my database has 2 tables, foo & foo2.

Table foo2 has two records

```
id=1, code="N", desc="Normal"

id=2, code="D", desc="Deviate"
```

I want to populate foo but I need to reference foo2 in doing so. My current code is:

```
 $inputarray = array(
 array("ONE", "Proj 1", "N"),
 array("TWO", "Proj 2", "D"));

for ($i = 0; $i < count($inputarray); $i++) {
$sql3 = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO foo (var1, var2, var3)
      VALUES ('{$inputarray[$i][0]}'
             ,'{$inputarray[$i][1]}'
             , (select id from foo2 where code='($inputarray[$i][3])')
                        )");
$sql3->execute();}`
```

The "select id .." line generates an SQL error message but if I hard code it like

```
(select id from foo2 where code='N')
```

then the program runs without error.  I have tried escape characters, using double quotes inside the single quotes etc. How can i best get around this problem?

The code to create foo was

```
$sql2 = $pdo->prepare('
    CREATE TABLE foo(
        id    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        var1  VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        var2  VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
        var3  INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
        FOREIGN KEY (var3) REFERENCES foo2 (id)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT) ENGINE=INNODB');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the way to use prepared statements

```
$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO foo (var1, var2, var3)
     VALUES ('{$inputarray[$i][0]}'
         ,'{$inputarray[$i][1]}'
         , (select id from foo2 where code='($inputarray[$i][3])')
                    )");
```

This is plain old string concatenation, for all practical purposes you might as well use `mysql_*` functions here. The proper way to use PDO is like this:

```
$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO foo (var1, var2, var3)
     VALUES (?,?,  (select id from foo2 where code=?))");

$pdo->bindParam(1, $inputarray[$i][0])
$pdo->bindParam(2, $inputarray[$i][1])
$pdo->bindParam(3, $inputarray[$i][3])
```

Note how much more readable your code has become? You can avoid the repetitve calls to [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) by directly passing in the parameters to [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).

ps: To make your current code work `{$inputarray[$i][3]}` note the newly added curly brackets

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer @e4c5

Comment: Glad to have helped